# CMake setup for Project with multiple .exe for game engine

Tags: c++, cmake

I am working on a game engine using CMake, this being the first CMake project I worked on I am looking for some feedback.

The project has the following structure:

```
root
|--CMakeLists.txt
|--Cheetah
|  |--CmakeLists.txt
|  |--includes
|  |--dependencies
|  |--src
|  |--out
|     |--build
|        |--x64-Debug
|
|--CheetahGUI
|  |--CmakeLists.txt
|  |--src
|  |--out
|     |--build
|        |--x64-Debug
|
|--Game
|  |--CmakeLists.txt
|  |--src
|  |--out
|     |--build
|        |--x64-Debug
|
|--|--out
|     |--build
|        |--x64-Debug
|           |--Cheetah
|           |--CheetahGUI
|           |--Game
```

**Cheetah(dynamic library)**
is the Engine library, it contains the API's for creating a game.

**CheetahGUI(.exe)**
is the engine's UI, capable of running the game inside the UI.

- depends on Cheetah
- depends on Game

**Game(dynamic library/.exe)**
Is the game project, and gets build to both dll and .exe, dll for use in the engineGUI and .exe for running the game without the engineGUI

- depends on Cheetah

Currently have the feeling I mix up all kinds of techniques and it is messy. So I'm looking for feedback on the following points:

- Is the code style consistent and using standards
- Are dependencies included in the right way
- Is it extendable
  of course other feedback is also much appreciated!

Also I have the following questions:

- Is adding each source file by path to the target the right way?(I've seen file(GLOB) but everywhere I look they advise against using it).
- Currently I name the Game.dll target Game_lib what results in Game_lib.dll is there a way to name both targets for the .exe and .dll both Game?

Many thanks in advance!

**Cheetah/CMakeLists.txt**

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Cheetah, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
project ("Cheetah")

# Platform defines
IF (WIN32)
  add_compile_definitions(CH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
ELSE()
  # set stuff for other systems
ENDIF(WIN32)

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD CHEETAH LIBRARY
#----------------------------------------------

# Define Cheetah variables
set(LIB_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies")
set(INCLUDES_DIR_PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/includes")
set(INCLUDES_DIR_PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(ENGINE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Engine")
set(ENGINE_CORE_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Core")
set(ENGINE_INPUT_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Input")
set(ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Events")
set(ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Renderer")
set(ENGINE_DEBUG_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Debug")
set(ENGINE_MATH_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Math")
set(ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Resources")
set(ENGINE_UTILS_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Utils")
set(ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/ImGUI")
set(ENGINE_ASSETS_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Assets")
set(ENGINE_FILES_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Files")
set(ENGINE_METRICS_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Metrics")
set(ENGINE_DATABASE_DIR "${ENGINE_DIR}/Database")
set(PLATFORM_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Platform")
set(PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR "${PLATFORM_DIR}/Windows")
set(PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR "${PLATFORM_DIR}/OpenGL")

# Set default files
list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES    
    "${ENGINE_DIR}/Engine.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Application.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Application.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/ApplicationManager.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/ApplicationManager.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Core.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/EntryPoint.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Window.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayer.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayer.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayerQueue.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/UpdateLayerQueue.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/ImGUILayer.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Time.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Time.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/Memory.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAction.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAction.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/GraphicsContext.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/GraphicsContext.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAPI.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderAPI.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderManager.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/RenderManager.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer2D.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer2D.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/IndexBuffer.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/IndexBuffer.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBuffer.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBuffer.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexArray.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexArray.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Shader.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Shader.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBufferLayout.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/VertexBufferLayout.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Texture.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Texture.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Camera.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Camera.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/PerspectiveCamera.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/PerspectiveCamera.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/OrthoGraphicCamera.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/OrthoGraphicCamera.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/BasicShapes2D.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/BasicShapes2D.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Vertex.h"
    "${ENGINE_INPUT_DIR}/Input.h"
    "${ENGINE_INPUT_DIR}/Input.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/ApplicationEvents.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/ApplicationEvents.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/Event.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/Event.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/EventDispatcher.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/EventDispatcher.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/EventTypes.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/InputEvents.h"
    "${ENGINE_EVENTS_DIR}/InputEvents.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_MATH_DIR}/Math.h"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceCache.h"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceCache.inl"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceLoader.h"
    "${ENGINE_RESOURCES_DIR}/ResourceLoader.cpp"    
    "${ENGINE_ASSETS_DIR}/AssetManager.h"
    "${ENGINE_ASSETS_DIR}/AssetManager.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_FILES_DIR}/AssetTypes.h"
    "${ENGINE_FILES_DIR}/FileManager.h"
    "${ENGINE_FILES_DIR}/FileManager.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_METRICS_DIR}/MemoryMetrics.h"
    "${ENGINE_METRICS_DIR}/MemoryMetrics.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_DATABASE_DIR}/DatabaseManager.h"
    "${ENGINE_DATABASE_DIR}/DatabaseManager.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_DATABASE_DIR}/Models.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer3D.h"
    "${ENGINE_RENDERER_DIR}/Renderer3D.cpp"
)
# Set platform specific files
# Windows
list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES_WINDOWS
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsWindow.h"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsWindow.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsTime.h"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsTime.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsInput.h"
    "${PLATFORM_WINDOWS_DIR}/WindowsInput.cpp"
)

# OpenGL
list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES_OPENGL
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLRenderAPI.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLRenderAPI.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLGraphicsContext.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLGraphicsContext.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexBuffer.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexBuffer.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLIndexBuffer.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLIndexBuffer.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLShader.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLShader.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexArray.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLVertexArray.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLTexture.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLTexture.cpp"
)

#ImGUI
list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES_IMGUI
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/ImGUIManager.h"
    "${ENGINE_CORE_DIR}/ImGUIManager.cpp"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLImGUIManager.h"
    "${PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR}/OpenGLImGUIManager.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imconfig.h"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_demo.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_draw.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_internal.h"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imgui_widgets.cpp"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imstb_rectpack.h"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imstb_textedit.h"
    "${ENGINE_IMGUI_DIR}/imstb_truetype.h"
)

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES_OPENGL})

IF(CHEETAH_GUI_BUILD)
    list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES_IMGUI})
ENDIF()

# Append Platform specific files
# Operating platform
IF (WIN32)
  list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES_WINDOWS})
  # TODO: Linux
  # TODO: MacOS
  # TODO: Android
  # TODO: IOS
ENDIF(WIN32)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_library(Cheetah SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories (Cheetah INTERFACE ${INCLUDES_DIR_PUBLIC})
target_include_directories (Cheetah PRIVATE ${ENGINE_DIR})
target_include_directories (Cheetah PRIVATE ${INCLUDES_DIR_PRIVATE})

# Add compile definitions
list(APPEND CHEETAH_COMP_DEFS
    "CHEETAH_BUILD"
    ${RENDER_API}
)

target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PRIVATE ${CHEETAH_COMP_DEFS})
target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:DEBUG>")
target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PUBLIC IMGUI_IMPL_OPENGL_LOADER_GLAD=1)

set_target_properties(Cheetah PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

IF(APPLICATION_NAME)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET Cheetah 
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Cheetah.dll"
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}"
    )
ENDIF(APPLICATION_NAME)

IF(CHEETAH_GUI_BUILD)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET Cheetah 
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Cheetah.dll"
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CheetahGUI"
    )
ENDIF()

IF(CHEETAH_GUI_BUILD)
    target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PUBLIC "CHEETAH_GUI_BUILD")
ENDIF()
IF(GAME_BUILD)
    target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PUBLIC "GAME_BUILD")
ENDIF()

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD OPENGL LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(Cheetah ${OpenGL})

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD GLFW LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
set(GLFW_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glfw")
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW example programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW test programs")
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Build the GLFW documentation")
set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE INTERNAL "Generate installation target")
add_subdirectory("${GLFW_DIR}")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PRIVATE "${GLFW_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah "glfw" "${GLFW_LIBRARIES}")
target_compile_definitions(Cheetah PRIVATE "GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE")

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD GLAD LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
set(GLAD_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glad")
add_library("glad" "${GLAD_DIR}/src/glad.c")
target_include_directories("glad" PRIVATE "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PUBLIC "${GLAD_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah "glad" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD STB_IMAGE LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
set(STB_IMAGE_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/stb_image")
add_library("stb_image" "${STB_IMAGE_DIR}/stb_image.cpp")
target_include_directories("stb_image" PRIVATE "${STB_IMAGE_DIR}/include")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PUBLIC "${STB_IMAGE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah "stb_image" "${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}")

#---------------------------------------------
# ADD GLM LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
# --------------------------------------------
set(GLM_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/glm")
add_subdirectory("${GLM_DIR}")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PRIVATE "${GLM_DIR}/glm")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah glm)

#---------------------------------------------
# ADD SQLITE LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
# --------------------------------------------
set(SQLITE_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/sqlite")
add_library("sqlite3" "${SQLITE_DIR}/sqlite3.c")
target_include_directories("sqlite3" PRIVATE "${SQLITE_DIR}")
target_include_directories(Cheetah PUBLIC "${SQLITE_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(Cheetah "sqlite3")

#---------------------------------------------
# ADD FONTAWESOME FONT DEPENDENCY
# --------------------------------------------
target_include_directories(Cheetah PUBLIC "${LIB_DIR}/fontAwesome")
```

**CheetahGUI/CMakeLists.txt**

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Cheetah, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CheetahGUI/src")
set(GUI_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CheetahGUI/src/GUI")
set(IMGUI_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CheetahGUI/src/ImGUI")
set(GUI_CORE_DIR "${GUI_DIR}/Core")
set(GUI_COMPONENTS_DIR "${GUI_DIR}/Components")
set(GUI_WINDOWS_DIR "${GUI_DIR}/Windows")
set(PLATFORM_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CheetahGUI/src/Platform")
set(PLATFORM_OPENGL_DIR "${PLATFORM_DIR}/OpenGL")

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES 
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp"
    "${GUI_CORE_DIR}/EditorLayer.h"
    "${GUI_CORE_DIR}/EditorLayer.cpp"
    "${GUI_CORE_DIR}/MainDockingPort.h"
    "${GUI_CORE_DIR}/MainDockingPort.cpp"
    "${GUI_COMPONENTS_DIR}/MenuBar/MenuBar.h"
    "${GUI_COMPONENTS_DIR}/MenuBar/MenuBar.cpp"
    "${GUI_COMPONENTS_DIR}/DropDown/DropDown.h"
    "${GUI_COMPONENTS_DIR}/DropDown/DropDown.cpp"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/EditorWindow.h"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/EditorWindow.cpp"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/SceneExplorer/SceneExplorer.h"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/SceneExplorer/SceneExplorer.cpp"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/AssetExplorer/AssetExplorer.h"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/AssetExplorer/AssetExplorer.cpp"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/SceneView/SceneView.h"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/SceneView/SceneView.cpp"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/MemoryMetrics/MemoryMetrics.h"
    "${GUI_WINDOWS_DIR}/MemoryMetrics/MemoryMetrics.cpp"
)

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${OPENGL_SOURCE})

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES ${OPENGL_FILES_GUI})

# Platform defines
IF (WIN32)
  add_compile_definitions(CH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
ELSE()
  # set stuff for other systems
ENDIF()

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable(CheetahGUI ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(CHEETAH_GUI_BUILD "CHEETAH_GUI_BUILD" CACHE INTERNAL "")

target_compile_definitions(CheetahGUI PUBLIC CHGUI_BUILD_DLL)
target_include_directories(CheetahGUI PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/includes")
target_include_directories(CheetahGUI PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CheetahGUI/dependencies")
target_include_directories(CheetahGUI PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CheetahGUI/src")

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
target_link_libraries(CheetahGUI Cheetah)
target_link_libraries(CheetahGUI Game_lib)

#----------------------------------------------
# ADD OPENGL LIBRARY DEPENDENCY
#----------------------------------------------
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(CheetahGUI ${OpenGL})
```

**Game/CMakeLists.txt**

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for Cheetah, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/src")
set(INCLUDES_DIR_PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Game/includes")

list(APPEND MAIN
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Main.cpp"
)

list(APPEND SOURCE_FILES 
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Core.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameLayer.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/GameLayer.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/MainCamera.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/MainCamera.cpp"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Game.h"
    "${SOURCE_DIR}/Game.cpp"

)

# Platform defines
IF (WIN32)
  add_compile_definitions(CH_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)
ELSE()
  # set stuff for other systems
ENDIF()

add_library(Game_lib SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_compile_definitions(Game_lib PUBLIC G_BUILD_DLL)
target_include_directories(Game_lib PRIVATE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Cheetah/includes")
target_link_libraries(Game_lib Cheetah)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET Game_lib 
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Game/Game_lib.dll"
    "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/CheetahGUI"
)

list(APPEND MAIN ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (Game ${MAIN})

target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Cheetah/includes")

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
target_link_libraries(Game Cheetah)
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("Game")

set(APPLICATION_NAME "Game")
set(RENDER_API "OPENGL")

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory("Cheetah")
add_subdirectory ("Game")
add_subdirectory("CheetahGUI")
```